# Trigger preventing insert

Tags: t-sql, triggers

Is there any reason that having a trigger on a table would prevent the original insert statement from inserting? The trigger is run AFTER the row is inserted in the table, and there is no transaction rollback in the trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will happen when there is an exception in the trigger (when an error happens in a trigger the batch is aborted).

Comment: This is why testing  trigger code is critical and it has to be written so that there are no possible bugs. It is also why it is a bad idea to call an outside process in a trigger. If you send an email from a trigger and outlook is down, oops no records can be added.